# Theory? Upload a File on a Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script

I am a newbie but have read on this site and others that 
1.  Google Forms cannot handle File uploads
2.  For file uploads, you need a custom HTML form published as a webapp. 
But the webapp can only be embedded in a Google Site and not a Google Form.

Can someone explain to me why Google Forms cannot handle file uploads? Why can't a file upload action be triggered by a form event such as filling out a text field with a file name?  Or why can't a button on the form launch a custom form that has a file upload button?

Why can't HTML or a Webapp be imbedded within a Google Form?  Is it possible to view the source code for a Google Form?  I only see the WYSIWYG UI for creating forms and I have seen the scripting in the results spreadsheet of a form only.

Finally:
3.  THe education version of Google has a file upload feature on their Forms.  How can I get a copy of their source code to study how they did it?

4. As a last resort, I figured out that a  hyperlink to a webapp can be added to a Google Form simply by typing the URL.  How do I give the hyperlink a friendlier title like "Click here to upload a file" ?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: A file upload feature is available to GSuite Business accounts.  What does this tell us?  Firstly, the functionality for file uploads in a Google Form has already been developed, but for some reason, Google has restricted this functionality to *exclude* free accounts.  This is obviously a strategy to get revenue by providing a different level of service to paid accounts.  I don't blame them for that.  So, you need to understand this issue from the perspective of what Google's objective is.  It's not that hard to add a file upload feature.  Google Forms are restricted on purpose.

Comment: You can use the development tools in most browsers to see the HTML, JavaScript and CSS that has been served to the browser.  That won't give you how the HTML, etc was constructed on the server.  A file upload button in HTML is no secret.  The problem is, you would need to be able to modify the HTML, CSS and JavaScript in the Google Form.  How are you going to do that?  And even if there is a way to do it, it's probably not viable to do for users in general.  In the time it took you to figure out how to hack the Google Form, you could have built your own input form.

Comment: Thank you Sandy Good, I appreciate your spelling out the issues for me.  Do you know if I can change the text of a hyperlink on a form?  So I can click on a link in a Google Form to go to a custom form that has the upload button.  But hide the URL of the custom form and have a hyperlink that says "Upload"

Comment: A "Title and Description" can be added to the Form, and in the Description, you can enter a link.  Click the icon that has two "T's" on it.